# Is it possible to pool standardized differences across multiple imputations after matching in R?

Tags: r, multiple-imputation, matching

Are there any statistical procedures to pool standardized differences across multiple imputations after matching in R? I am aware of pooled estimates using mira but I just want the pooled standardized difference across imputation.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cobalt` package does this. See the vignette on segmented data on the package's [CRAN page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cobalt/) (also accessible through its [website](https://ngreifer.github.io/cobalt/articles/cobalt_A2_segmented_data.html#multiply-imputed-data-1)).

To do matching and weighting with multiply imputed data, look into the `MatchThem` package, which was specifically designed for this purpose and is directly compatible with `cobalt`, so using it is simple.